# Remove embedded image data from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to use BS4 to remove embedded images to save space, but to leave the tag. For example remove the base64 data but leave `<img class="blah" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<DELETED>`

I can do this to remove everything including the tag:

```
tags=soup.findAll('img')
for match in tags:
  match.decompose()
```

Removes everything but I would like to keep the tag reference without the actual binary source.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3

```
markup = """
<div>
    <p>Take the red pill</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Follow the white rabbit" />
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.img
tag['src'] = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"

print(tag)
```

Outputs

```
<img alt="Follow the white rabbit" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to do it. Easy really?

```
for match in tags:
  match['src']='deleted'
```